# How to load and write properties file in a Spark Scala job?

Tags: java, scala, apache-spark

I have a job Spark and I should read properties information from a file "config.properties" in this format:

```
var1=1
var2=12/10/2021
```

At the end of the process, I should update `var1` and `var2` , so I have to overwrite "config.properties" file.... how can I do ?

Comment: use json file instead of Properties file for keep variable.. if your use case is to update variable after process.

Comment: ok and how would you code it ?

Answer (score 1):

This code would be part of the driver, so you write it as any Java/Scala app reading a configuration files, whether the properties format or using JSON.

What you need to keep in mind:

- when you run in local mode (when you create your session with setMaster(“local”)) or client mode (setting up master to a known cluster) then you run locally. This means that the driver will access your local file system. Make sure the user running the app Ahmad the rights to do so.
- when in cluster mode, and you submit your application via Spark-submit or a similar tool, then you do not control the path and you may not be able to access a local file on the cluster. In this scenario, depending on your infrastructure, you may want to point to a cloud drive (S3 or equivalent), a network mount (SMB, NFS…), or a virtual drive (Google Drive, ownCloud, Dropbox…)